# Single pole to a 3 way?

Tags: wiring

We have a single gang box that needs to switch two single poles and a 3 way switch. I've only been able to find switches that house 3 single poles in a single gang space. Can I safely convert one of those switches to a three way switch?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "converting one of those switches".  A switch is either a single pole or a three way.  Do you want to convert the 3-way _circuit_ to only be controlled by one switch?

Comment: Can you change out to a 3-gang

Comment: You're wrestling with the wrong solution. Carefully work your box out of the wall buy either breaking it up or cutting the internal fasteners, then pop in a 2- or 3-gang remodeler (old work) box. If you do it right there'll be no drywall repair necessary.

Comment: Yes, is there a reason you're trying to cram this all into a single gang box instead of replacing the box?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will find one. For simplicity (fewer SKUs), you will generally find "everything the same". So that would mean "3 regular switches" or "3 3-way switches". But due to box fill limits (see [Looking for triple 3-way switch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126627/looking-for-triple-3-way-switch) ) plus I suspect limited demand to figure out a solution, a triple 3-way doesn't seem to exist.

What might work is a smart switch. Many smart switches have "remotes" that are either battery powered or just use a few wires to get power, control power and *communicate* to other switches. But in a quick search I didn't see any single gang triple switches.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't cram nearly that many wires into that box

And it creates ugly UX if you do.

Your only hope, really, is to fit a 4-11/16" square metal box (42 cubic inches) then a 1-gang "mud ring" that portrudes through the drywall.  The large box sits entirely inside the wall, and you reach it through the 2x4" hole of the 1-gang box.  Every wire must stick out at least 3" beyond the surface of the wall, even the wires that only splice in that box.

Let's take the brst case: #14 wire (2.0 cubic inches per wire) all three cables are "switch loops" (a spur off the rest of the circuit.) You need

- 3: Switched-hot and 2 travelers for the 3-way circuit if neutral is not required in this box
- 3: Always-not, switched-hot ***and neutral*** for one of the 2-ways
- 3: ditto for the other 2-way
- 1 for all grounds
- 1 for all cable clamps
- 2 "wires" for the yoke containing the 3 switches

Neutral must come into the box as of NEC 2011,   and switch loops cannot borrow neutrals from other circuits. (Nothing can borrow a neutral.)

That is 13 wires at 26 cubic inches, *best case*. Way, way too much for any 1-gang box, and at limits of a 4" square box with a mud ring.  So yeah, you need the 4-11/16" box, you just don't need to *see it*.

This, too, presumes you can find a 3/2/2-way switch on the marketplace.  I doubt you will; putting 6 screws on a yoke is hard, putting 7 is nigh impossible.  I suppose one of the switches could be pigtails, or it could eliminate screws by forcing the always-hot to be common. That doesn't work on switch loops, you can't "borrow" hots either.  On the upside, if it's pigtails, those are "free" in cubic inch calculations.